# Sound can't be defined in if statement

Tags: javascript, audio

I have a code like this:

```
    var snd = [new Audio("bla/blo.wav"), new Audio("bla/bli.wav")]

    function playSnd(x) {
        if (x == 1) {snd[0].play()}
        if (x == 2) {snd[1].play()}
    }

    playSnd(2)
```

Here at the "playSnd(2)" is the problem, it will play both of the sounds, why???

Comment: Edited it... ([0] and [0])

Comment: Impossible. In this universe `2!=1`.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard Semicolons are not mandatory although recommended.

Comment: I don't get any console errors, but anyways how can I fix this?

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is, exactly.

Comment: @Mich' Fix what? The code is correct. If there is a problem, then not in that code.

Comment: Then run it, both sounds will be played not only snd[1]

Comment: With given code only 2nd sound is played. Tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/qvbHG/1/  Is there any more code on you page?

Comment: @Sergej Popov   alot of code, it's for a tictactoe game

Answer (score 0):

```
var snd = ["bla/blo.wav", "bla/bli.wav"]

function playSnd(x) {
    if (x == 1) {(new Audio( snd[0] )).play()}
    if (x == 2)  {(new Audio( snd[1] )).play()}
}

playSnd(2)
```

Comment: Before anyone says this doesn't answer the question, it does address the question in the title. Just not the question in the posting.

Comment: Yeah IK that was just what I tried but since I don't want to load the sound every time it should be played I dont accept your answer.

Comment: In that case you might need more powerful technology such as the [Web Audio API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/).

Answer (score -3):

I cant seem to find anything wrong with your code. But you could start with using an else if to debug where your code is going wrong.

```
var snd = [new Audio("bla/blo.wav"), new Audio("bla/bli.wav")]

function playSnd(x) {
    if (x == 1) {snd[0].play()}
    else if (x == 2) {snd[1].play()}
}

playSnd(2)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.